# Can I plug my cable telephone outlet directly into the wall socket?

Tags: telephone

I have POTS telephone service from cable modem.

Recently I got a new modem. So, the old modem was removed. The old modem was in the basement and wired up to the telephone system in a rats nest of wires by the installer.

The new modem is upstairs in my study. I only have my office phone plugged into it, so right now it is the only phone in the house that works.

Can I use a jack splitter in the office telephone wall jack, then plug the office phone into one half and the modem into the other. If I do this will all the phones start working again?

I cannot just test this, because I will need to buy a jack splitter and a phone cord RJ25 or whatever, so I don't want to go the trouble of doing this, if it will not work.

Comment: Off-topic for this site, but yes that will probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if the house POTS is no longer connected to the old modem, you can split and connect your VOIP line to the household RJ-45 Line 1. (center pair Tip/Ring)  while Line 2 (Outer pair) can be used for anything else.